# What is the name for all sizes and environments web application architecture?

Tags: web-applications

For further reading, I need the name of the concept of a web application for all common screen sizes and environments ("desktop"/"laptop"/"tablet"/"Smartphone").

That is, in the past some people created both a "mobile website" and a "mobile application" (both could run on Smartphones; the first ran on smartphone browsers and the second natively on smartphones.

but if I want both the smartphone-browser and smartphone-native version to be **totally identical** what is the name of methodology I should develop in?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the term [responsive web design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

"Responsive" is one of three [ways of building mobile sites that Google supports](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/) for SEO.  The three are:

- **Responsive web design** - Uses the same HTML code for all devices but uses CSS rules to reformat the page based on the size of the screen.
- **Dynamic serving** - Detects the device type based on the user agent string, and sends different HTML code to different devices.
- **Separate URLs** - Separate mobile and desktop sites with redirects between them based on device type.

Responsive web design usually starts with a meta tag that makes mobile devices show the site fully zoomed in:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It typically uses CSS rules based on screen size.  Here those rules simply change the background color, but they often change element size or change columns into blocks.

```
body {
    /* big screens */
    background-color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    body {
      /* medium screens */
      background-color: yellow;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    body {
        /* small screens */
        backgund-color: green;
    }
}
```

It may use units in CSS that are relative to the screen size:

- `vw` - percents of screen width.  `1vw` is 1% of the screen width.
- `vh` - percents of screen height. `1vh` is 1% of the screen height.
- `vmin` - percents of width or height, whichever is less.
- `vmax` - percents of width or height, whichever is more.

For example this rule allows fonts on larger screens to be larger:

```
body {
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

Images are often also dynamically sized based on the screen size:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Responsive web design may also require changes to JavaScript to detect which features browsers detect.  Browsers that don't support certain features may require special code.

Comment: Hello ! I am not sure this is the term I am looking for (I know that term from about 2010) because all responsive websites I have seen had 2 different versions for mobile browser and mobile smartphone application. Hence, I humbly conclude that a situation were a mobile-version of a website and the smartphone application are identical (have the exact same styling), requires a different term...